# Why is everything in the Windows API typedef'd?

Tags: c, winapi, typedef

More specifically, why is the same thing `typedef`'d with multiple different names in many cases, and why `typedef` pointer types (obscuring logic at times)?

For example:

`typedef  const WCHAR *LPCWSTR, *PCWSTR;`

What is the point of that?

Comment: I don't know the full details of everything but think back in the 16-bit days with Windows 3.1.  There were two different types of pointers back then, near and far pointers.  They defined pointer types for each (`PCWSTR` and `LPCWSTR` respectively) for a uniform interface.  Due to the backwards compatibility that Microsoft was aiming for, we're left with both these types in the API due to it.

Comment: The real question is, why do they typedef away other pointer types that don't have the far pointer history behind them? Such as HANDLE, HWND, HINSTANCE etc. As far as I know, there is no rational answer to that question.

Comment: @Lundin: HANDLE, HWND and so on are not actually pointers: they are opaque handles that are private to some part of Windows (USER, GDI, KERNEL). Behind the scenes, they may actually be used as indices into internal tables or similar. They are typedef'd as void* specifically to make it clear that they should only be passed around as-is and code should not attempt to interpret them (eg. by doing arithmetic on them - which would be easy to do by accident if they were say int values); a different purpose than what's going on with the typedefs in the qu above.

Comment: From MS docs on [Windows Coding Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/windows-coding-conventions#pointer-types): "On 16-bit architectures there are 2 types of pointers, P for "pointer" and LP stands for "long pointer". <...> Today there is no distinction, and these pointer types are all equivalent. Avoid using these prefixes; or if you must use one, then use P."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason there is both PCWSTR and LPCWSTR is that in ancient times there was a difference. LPCWSTR used to be const WCHAR FAR *.

Answer (score 24):

There's actually a few different things going on here:

- First the Near/Far pointers: Back in Win16 days, you had near and far pointers; near pointers were basically just 16 bits offsets, so could only refer to objects within 64k of an app's default data pointer (DS or Data Segment register), but they were small and fast; whereas a larger 'far pointer' or long pointer consisted of both segment and offset, so could refer to anything within the 1M address space. When the 386 came along, all this segment:offset business finally went away, and all pointers were just 32 bit addresses into flat 32bit address spaces. And that's why there's both P... and LP... versions.
- Why bother with typedefs in the first place? It's just a convenience or shorthand: typing "LPSTR" is more convenient than "const char far *". But it also becomes a recognizable idiom: you see LPSTR and know straight away that it's how Windows deals with strings in its API.
- There's also an abstraction going on here: Windows generally defines its own versions of types and uses them instead of the C versions. So Windows APIs use DWORD instead of int, or VOID instead of void. This was needed to plug some holes in C at the time - there was no bool, so introducing BOOL avoided having different APIs use different types to represent boolean values (eg char vs int). It also to some extent made the Windows API independent of an underlying C implementation: C doesn't require that int is a specific size: it could be 16 bits or 32 bits depending on the compiler. But for an OS API, its important to specify these things exactly. So rather than using int or long, Windows instead uses INT and LONG, which it then defines as needed, and typedefs to whatever underlying C type does the actual job.
- Finally, some of these typedefs are actually hinting at specific usages beyond just type information. BOOL and INT are both typedef'd as int, but it's clear that an API parameter specified as BOOL is going to be used in a TRUE/FALSE sense, not as an integer value. (Remember that this predates the 'bool' type.) Likewise, BYTE - which is unsigned char - suggests that a parameter is actually going to be used as a 8-bit numberic value rather than as a alphanumeric or symbol character. And LPSTR indicates that the value is expected to be a NUL-terminated string, rather than just pointing to arbitrary char values. BSTR and LPWSTR have the same underlying typedef - they're both WCHAR * - but BSTRs have a length prefix and so must be allocated with the SysAllocString API, having a separate typedef here helps keep the two separate in code and document API requirements: if you see an API that takes a BSTR as a parameter, then you know that you can't just pass in a wide string, even though the underlying type is the same, there's additional requirements for that parameter.

Comment: What is the point of having a pointer typedef of every type then? (`BYTE`, `PBYTE`)

Comment: Likely related to the first point above - since there used to be two distinct types of pointers (near/far) for any given type, it's convenient and consistent to have typedefs (P... and LP...) for *both* that follow a consistent pattern and which abstracted away whatever the appropriate compiler vendor keywords/modifiers were. A lot of this only makes sense in the context of the original Win16 world were these typedefs are created: if that near/far pointer distinction never existed, then BYTE/BYTE* would have worked just as well.

Answer (score 4):

I believe one of the main goals of this design is to allow the types of the functions to serve as documentation of their purpose and expected data formats.

Comment: What is the difference between `LP` and `P` in the `typedef`s for pointer types?  I mean above we see an instance where they're `typedef`d to the same thing...

Comment: I could be wrong on this, but I think that it's a historical artifact from 16-bit Windows, where you had both pointers and 'long pointers'. They were separate types then, but only 1 type is needed now. Both are supported for backwards compatibility.