# Why are C and C++ keywords "#defined" or "typedefed" as their capital versions too?

Tags: c++, c, typedef, c-preprocessor

Sorry for the confusing title but I couldn't think of a title that would describe my question clearly. When writing a C or C++ program, you can usually refer to keywords such as char with CHAR, or int with INT, or void with VOID, and on.

In winnt.h, they are defined as follows:

```
#ifndef VOID
#define VOID void
typedef char CHAR;
typedef short SHORT;
typedef long LONG;
#if !defined(MIDL_PASS)
typedef int INT;
#endif
#endif
```

What is the use of doing this? Is it to satisfy convention or ensure compatibility?

Comment: It's called Windows being weird.

Comment: Haha ok. Because sometimes functions are declared as returning VOID and sometimes void, so I assumed it was some sort of convention

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is everything in the Windows API typedef'd?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889642/why-is-everything-in-the-windows-api-typedefd) - See the accepted answer there...

Comment: "When writing a C or C++ program, you can usually (...)" No. Only on Windows and only if you include (directly or indirectly) `winnt.h`. And I see no reason to do that in "modern" programs anyway.

Comment: Ok, so is it just to satisfy some Windows convention

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Looks like the answer in that link which does talk about this is not the accepted one (though it has the most votes).

Comment: It _might_ be from an influence of assembler. Many assembly programmers use all caps for such definitions.

Comment: What is this question intended to be about? Why standard types are aliased (through `#define` or `typedef`)? Or why the aliases are capitalized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capitalized (#defined) versions are often used to allow the code to be made compatible with various compilers.  And typedefs are typically used to ensure the newly named types meet stricter rules than the originals defined by the compiler.

Typically, `typedef int INT`, or the like can be seen inside blocks that are detecting the compiler-environment, so that a name like "INT" can be used to provide more restrictive semantics that "int".

In "C", all primitive types, like `int` and `char`, are "at least" a certain size (I don't know that size right now).  Which means the compiler is allowed to make them larger.  I know of a system that used a 32-bit char type.  This leads to easily writing non-portable code when assumptions are made, such as assuming "int" is always 32 bits.

An experiment in your environment might help.  Try a small program like the following and then compile and run it with 32-bit settings and then 64-bit settings:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("sizeof INT=%u\n", sizeof (INT));
    printf("sizeof int=%u\n", sizeof (int));
}
```

As far as VOID, defining it to "void" is a little odd. However, it looks like - in the snippet given - it's being used to determine if the others have already been defined by the same header file - which is a very important step in "C" since duplicate typedefs lead to errors.  IIRC, duplicate defines can lead to errors or warnings, denpending on the compiler and settings.

Comment: If `INT` is the same type as `int`, then it's not useful other than for consistency with other all-caps type names. If `INT` can be something other than `int`, then that's horribly confusing, and a different name (maybe `WORD`) should have been chosen.

Comment: The reasons behind this actually harken back to the transition between 16-bit / 32-bit API where the built-in `int` used to be a 16-bit word and they were trying to make INT be the 32-bit form (MFC 1.1 to MFC 2.0)

Comment: @KeithThompson: `WORD` actually names a 16 bits unsigned type, e.g. `std::uint16_t` or `unsigned short`. There's `DWORD`, which is 32 bits but unsigned.

Comment: @MSalters: I think `WORD` and `DWORD` are Microsoft-specific. I can imagine someone defining `WORD` as a 32-bit unsigned type -- though given the conflict with the Microsoft-specific definition, it would probably be a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

I've always thought of these trivial typedefs (e.g. int -> INT) to be more about consistency of than anything.

What I mean by this, is that there are many many typedefs in Win32 in caps - DWORD, WORD, LPARAM, WPARAM, HANDLE, HWND,  some of these are simply integers and their name provides context as to their use, and some of them (eg RECT and WNDCLASS) represent structures.

Consider the case of function void f(int, BOOL, char, PAINTSTRUCT); to me it feels more consitent to allow all capitals: VOID f(INT, BOOL, CHAR, PAINTSTRUCT). But that could just be me.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly convention if I'm not mistaken.  I think windows put some of them in their to ensure compatibility for some data types (integers for example, maintaining compatibility of 8 bit, 16 bit, 32 bit, etc.).